# Multiple consoles of Sypder are faster than mutliprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, spyder, python-multiprocessing

I am running a backtest for a trading strategy, defined as a class. I am trying to select the best combination of parameters to input in the model, so I am running multiple backtesting on a given period, trying out different combinations. The idea is to be able to select the first generation of a population to feed into a genetic algorithm. Seems like the perfect job for multiprocessing!

So I tried a bunch of things to see what works faster. I opened 10 Spyder consoles (yes, I tried it) and ran a single combination of parameters for each console (all running at the same time).

The sample code used for each single Spyder console:

```
class MyStrategy(day,parameters):
   # my strategy that runs on a single day

backtesting=[]
for day in days:
   backtesting_day=MyStrategy(day,single_parameter_combi)
   backtesting.append(backtesting_day)
```

I then tried the multiprocessing way, using pool.

The sample code used in multiprocessing:

```
class MyStrategy(day,parameters):
   # my strategy that runs on a single day

def single_run_backtesting(single_parameter_combi):
   backtesting=[]
   for day in days:
      backtesting_day=MyStrategy(day,single_parameter_combi)
      backtesting.append(backtesting_day)
   return backtesting

def backtest_many(list_of parameter_combinations):
   p=multiprocessing.pool()
   result=p.map(single_run_backtesting,list_of parameter_combinations)
   p.close()
   p.join()
   return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
   parameter_combis=[...] # a list of parameter combinations, 10 different ones in this case
   result = backtest_many(parameter_combis)
```

I have also tried the following: opening 5 Spyder consoles and running 2 instances of the class in a for loop, as below, and a single Spyder console with 10 instances of the class.

```
class MyStrategy(day,parameters):
   # my strategy that runs on a single day

parameter_combis=[...] # a list of parameter combinations

backtest_dict={k: [] for k in range(len(parameter_combis)} # make a dictionary of empty lists

for day in days:
   for j,single_parameter_combi in enumerate(parameter_combis):
      backtesting_day=MyStrategy(day,single_parameter_combi)
      backtest_dict[j].append(backtesting_day)
```

To my great surprise, it takes around 25 minutes with multiprocessing to go thorugh a single day, about the same time with a single Spyder console with 10 instances of a class in the for loop, and magically it takes only 15 minutes when I run 10 Spyder consoles at the same time. How do I process this information? It doesn't really make sense to me. I am running a 12-cpu machine on windows 10.

Consider that I am planning to run things on AWS with a 96-core machine, with something like 100 combinations of parameters that cross in a genetic algorithm which should run something like 20-30 generations (a full backtesting is 2 business months = 44 days).

My question is: what am I missing??? Most importantly, is this just a difference in scale?
I know that for example if you define a simple squaring function and run it serially for 100 times, multiprocessing is actually slower than a for loop. You start seeing the advantage around 10000 times, see for example this: https://github.com/vprusso/youtube_tutorials/blob/master/multiprocessing_and_threading/multiprocessing/multiprocessing_pool.py

Will I see a difference in performance when I go up to 100 combinations with multiprocessing, and is there any way of knowing in advnace if this is the case? Am I properly writing the code? Other ideas? Do you think it would speed up significatively if I was to use multiprocessing one step "above", in a single parameter combination over many days?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) I have no answer to your question, but you said "I opened 10 Spyder istances". That's totally unnecessary. Instead, you can simply open ten consoles in the same instance and run your code with different parameters on each one of them.

Comment: that's what I did actually, I edited the question

Comment: Try `p.imap_unordered()`.

Comment: @AKX Using ```p.imap_unordered``` takes around 14 minutes! You sir have knowledge that would be very useful. Care to expand why you suggested this approach in a short answer?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba does Sypder do something like ```imap_unordered()``` under the hood when opening multiple consoles?

Comment: No. It doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand upon my comment "Try `p.imap_unordered()`.":

`p.map()` ensures that you get the results in the same order they're in the parameter list. To achieve this, some of the workers necessarily remain idle for some time 
For your use case – essentially a grid search of parameter combinations – you really don't need to have them in the same order, you just want to end up with the best option. (Additionally, [quoth the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map), "it may cause high memory usage for very long iterables. Consider using imap() or imap_unordered() with explicit chunksize option for better efficiency.")

[`p.imap_unordered()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered), by contrast, doesn't really care – it just queues things up and workers work on them as they free up.

It's also worth experimenting with the `chunksize` parameter – quoting the `imap()` documentation, "For very long iterables using a large value for chunksize can make the job complete much faster than using the default value of 1." (since you spend less time queueing and synchronizing things).

Finally, for your particular use case, you might want to consider having the master process generate an infinite amount of parameter combinations using a generator function, and breaking off the loop once you find a good enough solution or enough time passes.

A simple-ish function to do this and a contrived problem (finding two random numbers 0..1 to maximize their sum) follows. Just remember to return the original parameter set from the worker function too, otherwise you won't have access to it! :)

```py
import random
import multiprocessing
import time


def find_best(*, param_iterable, worker_func, metric_func, max_time, chunksize=10):
    best_result = None
    best_metric = None
    start_time = time.time()
    n_results = 0
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
        for result in p.imap_unordered(worker_func, param_iterable, chunksize=chunksize):
            n_results += 1
            elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
            metric = metric_func(result)
            if best_metric is None or metric > best_metric:
                print(f'{elapsed_time}: Found new best solution, metric {metric}')
                best_metric = metric
                best_result = result

            if elapsed_time >= max_time:
                print(f'{elapsed_time}: Max time reached.')
                break
    final_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(f'Searched {n_results} results in {final_time} s.')
    return best_result

# ------------

def generate_parameter():
    return {'a': random.random(), 'b': random.random()}


def generate_parameters():
    while True:
        yield generate_parameter()


def my_worker(parameters):
    return {
        'parameters': parameters,  # remember to return this too!
        'value': parameters['a'] + parameters['b'],  # our maximizable metric
    }


def my_metric(result):
    return result['value']


def main():
    result = find_best(
        param_iterable=generate_parameters(),
        worker_func=my_worker,
        metric_func=my_metric,
        max_time=5,
    )
    print(f'Best result: {result}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

An example run:

```
~/Desktop $ python3 so59357979.py
0.022627830505371094: Found new best solution, metric 0.5126700311039976
0.022940874099731445: Found new best solution, metric 0.9464256914062249
0.022969961166381836: Found new best solution, metric 1.2946600313637404
0.02298712730407715: Found new best solution, metric 1.6255217652861256
0.023016929626464844: Found new best solution, metric 1.7041449687571075
0.02303481101989746: Found new best solution, metric 1.8898109980050104
0.030200958251953125: Found new best solution, metric 1.9031436071918972
0.030324935913085938: Found new best solution, metric 1.9321951916206537
0.03880715370178223: Found new best solution, metric 1.9410837287942249
0.03970479965209961: Found new best solution, metric 1.9649277383314245
0.07829880714416504: Found new best solution, metric 1.9926667738329622
0.6105098724365234: Found new best solution, metric 1.997217792614364
5.000051021575928: Max time reached.
Searched 621931 results in 5.07216 s.
Best result: {'parameters': {'a': 0.997483, 'b': 0.999734}, 'value': 1.997217}
```

(By the way, this is nearly 6 times slower when `chunksize=1`.)

Comment: Great clarification. Correct me if I'm wrong: ```map``` is like a restaurant, a table only gets up when everyone finishes. ```imap_unordered``` is more like a buffet, everyone leaves when they're done.

Comment: Something like that! Or rather a buffet where everyone can go get more to eat (work on) without having to stay in an orderly queue.

Comment: And with the same analogy, `chunksize` is how many dishes each diner can get at a time without having to get up and walk back to the buffet and back. :)

Comment: about my case: I do not know what is "good enough" solution and break the loop, so I guess I'll try a small GA (20 generations) to get a sense of what I can get and later try your approach